# Rotate animation android

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to do a rotating image animation.
I need to rotate an icon around **itself** just like they do in a progressbar, but what I'm getting is an image rotating around a circle.
Here is my animation code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="2500"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="restart"
/>
```

Where am I going wrong in here?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I got where I was wrong. I gave padding to my image which caused it to move aside a little every time it rotated.
Anyhow I removed the padding and now it's working just fine.

Answer (score 69):

This is the source code for the layout main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="animationText" 
        android:onClick="AnimClick"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/testImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="image_desc"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/cat2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

To implement the rotation animation, we can define the animation by XML or Java code. If we want to write the animation in the xml, we need to create an animation xml file under /res/anim folder. Here, we create a xml file named `rotate_around_center_point.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="2500"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

and this is my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView animationTarget = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.testImage);

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_around_center_point);
        animationTarget.startAnimation(animation);

    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to add scaletype to the image and still it didn't help.

Answer (score 33):

You could try with the following code, rather than doing it in XML:

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        0.5f);

rotate.setDuration(4000);
rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
yourView.setAnimation(rotate);
```

Comment: you know how to avoid pause (stall) after the loop completes and before it repeats?

Comment: Try adding rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());