# How to rotate a text View 90 degree around itself?

Tags: android, animation

As I said I have a textView and I want to rotate it 90 degree. 
Problem is I don´t understand where I can set the fixed point.
I use this function

```
myTextView.animate().rotation(90).setDuration(1000).start();
```

this does rotate my view but it is always a little bit transformed in one direction.

My end result I want to be that here where the buttom of the text was befor now the right side of the text should be. and there where the left side was I now want the buttom.

Does anybody know how I can do that.
If nothing works I can use transformations to get the text at the right position but I don´t know whow large the text is and so I don´t know how to get the values for the transformation.

Comment: You can do by just adding a line to xml file.|

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rotated"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textColor="#44CC44"
    android:text="@string/rotated" />

Answer (score 1):

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 90,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        0.5f);

rotate.setDuration(4000);
rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
yourView.setAnimation(rotate);
```

For more detail check [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882967/rotate-animation-android)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnmi = (RotateAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.drawable.rorate);
rotateTv.setAnimation(rotateAnmi);
rotateTv.setGravity(Gravity.AXIS_X_SHIFT);
rotateTv.setText();
```